# How to quote paths on windows? (similar to shlex.quote)

Tags: python, windows, cmd, shlex

I need to quote a path in a portable way, `shlex.quote` is converting slashes to `/` on windows, which causes the command to fail *(using the default windows command prompt)*.

---

Returning `C:/Users/Me/Documents/Projects/Test`

Instead of `C:\Users\Me\Documents\Projects\Test`

---

How can I quote a path on windows, similar to `shlex.quote` that uses native slashes, suitable for the windows command prompt and BAT files?

Comment: Could you give an example of the input and output you want? Preferably in a case where `shlex.quote` doesn’t work for you?

Comment: Added example, exact use-case is here: https://developer.blender.org/D7666#184923

Comment: Reading the actual source code, I don’t see how it would transform backslashes to forward slashes. https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7f7e706d78ab968a1221c6179dfdba714860bd12/Lib/shlex.py#L325

Can you post a simple, single call to `shlex.quote` on windows that exhibits this behavior?    Not all SO users have access to Windows.

Comment: FYI, the linked example isn't an issue with the "command prompt" (CMD shell). To CMD, the importance of quoting paths in a command line of an external command is to avoid parsing special shell characters such as `&`. Parsing the command line itself into arguments is the job of the application. Most of them use [Microsoft C rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/parsing-c-command-line-arguments?view=vs-2019) via its `argv` argument parsing or similarly via WINAPI `CommandLineToArgvW`. You can build a command line per these rules via `subprocess.list2cmdline`.

Comment: For example, `subprocess.list2cmdline(['svn', 'ci', r'C:\path\with spaces', '-m', 'Update r6633'])` returns `'svn ci "C:\\path\\with spaces" -m "Update r6633"'`.

Comment: So the answer to this question could be: `subprocess.list2cmdline([path])` ?

Comment: If it's just a file path that you want to quote, then you can unconditionally wrap it in double quotes because double quote itself is a reserved wildcard character in every Windows filesystem. For example: `quoted_path = '"{}"'.format(os.path.normpath(path))`. Of course, to be safe you'd raise a `ValueError` if `path` contains an illegal double quote character.

Comment: Good to know, I wasn't aware that you couldn't use double-quote on windows *(not using Windows, just trying to write code that runs for windows users).*
This makes the answer even simpler.

Comment: NT filesystems have to reserve 5 wildcard characters: `*?"<>`. There's no escaping; they're just illegal in filenames. However, they're legal in stream names (e.g. `'filename:streamname*?"<>'`), but NTFS streams are so rarely used that many developers aren't even aware they exist.

Comment: The `*` and `?` wildcards in NT have simple semantics that one would expect. The last three are for the peculiar MS-DOS wildcard semantics that WINAPI `FindFirstFile` supports: `DOS_DOT` (`"`), `DOS_STAR` (`<`), and `DOS_QM` (`>`). A DOS wildcard pattern gets translated to use these 5 wildcard characters, and the filesystem is expected to filter a directory listing in the kernel using the pattern. In Unix, filtering a directory listing is a user-mode operation at the application level.

Comment: These comments are getting fairly deep into WIN32 filename handling, is there some answer to the original question here that a non-windows developer can use to write portable code?

Comment: @ideasman42, I suspect the premise of your question is not correct, and that `shlex.quote` is not responsible for converting the backslashes. Instead, I think your Python code might be constructing a `pathlib.Path` object at some point, and that is the source of slash conversions.

Comment: @NicholasM I don't use windows and had this reported from a windows developer. Whatever the case, knowing how to quote paths on Windows is a reasonable question, since there is an API function that handles this on Posix systems.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by some comments, your problem might not be caused by `shlex.quote()`.

Nevertheless there is the module [`mslex`](https://pypi.org/project/mslex/) which provides `mslex.quote()` and `mslex.split()` for the Windows shell, just like what `shlex` provides for the Unix shell.